# Is Cast double of float always same in the Java?

Tags: java, floating-point

Suppose we have a java float defined as `float p = 4.423`, will we always get same double value whenever `double q =(double) p` for the variable in the application flow, whenever it is cast as double?
Suppose there is another place, where I am accessing the variable `double r = (double) p`.  Will r be always equal to q?

Comment: Casting the same float value to a double will always give the same double value.

Comment: Why not try this yourself in a loop with random values?  See if you ever get a different result when comparing.

Comment: Yes, but remember that the _actual_ stored value is `4.422999858856201171875` because `4.423` is not exactly representable in floating point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*The Java Language Specification, Java SE 21 Edition*, §5.5 "Casting Contexts"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) specifies the conversions that a cast can perform. In the case of a conversion from `float` to `double`, the only one that's applicable is "a widening primitive conversion". [§5.1.2 "Widening Primitive Conversion"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) specifies that "A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value in the following cases, where the numeric value is preserved exactly", where one of the cases that it lists is "from `float` to `double`".

So every cast from a given `float` to a `double` must preserve the value of the `float` exactly, which in turn means it must give the same value every time. (Disclaimer: I'm not sure if that applies to NaN values, which aren't exactly "numeric values" and in any case aren't equal to themselves. But at least for a "normal" value like your example of `float p = 4.423`, we don't need to worry about that.)

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't prove it to be true but demonstrates a high confidence that it is.

```
Random r = new Random(123);
int n = 100_000_000;
double [] doubles = new double[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    doubles[i] = (double)r.nextFloat();
}
r.setSeed(123);  // generate same values anew
int count = 0;
for (double d : doubles) {
    if (d == (double)r.nextFloat()) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.printf("Count = %,d%n", count);
```

prints

```
Count = 100,000,000
```

But here is another way to look at it.  A float has a width of 32 bits.  Regardless of what the value is, it will fit in a double (width 64 bits) with no alteration needed. Thus, the converse of converting a `double that was previously a float` back to a `float` should not result in any change in the original `float` value.

So the following should compare the same as before.

```
count = 0;
r.setSeed(123);
for (double d : doubles) {
    if ((float)d == r.nextFloat()) {
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.printf("Count = %,d%n", count);
```

prints

```
Count = 100,000,000
```